# kubernetes unable to pull image docker private registry

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes

I tried to deploy 'deployments' in kubernetes which is pull docker image from private registry (I don't know who did this setup) but during "docker pull images" through kubernetes i'm getting following error

```
node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  85s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/trusted-enc-assettag1-deployment-8467b74958-6fbp7 to k8s-node
  Normal   BackOff    24s (x2 over 61s)  kubelet, k8s-node  Back-off pulling image "10.105.168.81:5000/simplehttpserverenc:enc_v1"
  Warning  Failed     24s (x2 over 61s)  kubelet, k8s-node  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    12s (x3 over 82s)  kubelet, k8s-node  Pulling image "10.105.168.81:5000/simplehttpserverenc:enc_v1"
  Warning  Failed     0s (x3 over 62s)   kubelet, k8s-node  Failed to pull image "10.105.168.81:5000/simplehttpserverenc:enc_v1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://10.105.168.81:5000/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
  Warning  Failed     0s (x3 over 62s)   kubelet, k8s-node  Error: ErrImagePull
[root@k8s-master ~]# docker pull 10.105.168.81:5000/simplehttpserverenc:enc_v1
```

ImagePullBackOff and net/http: TLS handshake timeout error.

Initially this "net/http: TLS handshake timeout" error is observed in docker pull as well. I referred some answers and

> configured certificate(/etc/docker/certs.d//ca.crt ) and
> proxy (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/proxy.conf)

after that able to perform docker pull from private image.

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# docker pull 10.105.168.81:5000/simplehttpserverenc:enc_v1
enc_v1: Pulling from simplehttpserverenc
54fec2fa59d0: Pull complete
cd3f35d84cab: Pull complete
a0afc8e92ef0: Pull complete
9691f23efdb7: Pull complete
6512e60b314b: Pull complete
a8ac6632d329: Pull complete
68f4c4e0aa8c: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:0358708cd11e96f6cf6f22b29d46a8eec50d7107597b866e1616a73a198fe797
Status: Downloaded newer image for 10.105.168.81:5000/simplehttpserverenc:enc_v1
10.105.168.81:5000/simplehttpserverenc:enc_v1
[root@k8s-master ~]#
```

But still unable to perform this docker pull through kubernetes. How to solve this ?

Comment: You should configure the same thing on the Kubernetes worker node hosts.

Comment: Did you create a docker-registry secret and use it in your deployment manifest? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Comment: I've configured, "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson" --> my-secret             kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1      39h

using docker login <regi IP> and then created secret.

Comment: @Daein Park I did now, but still , 

trusted-enc-assettag1-deployment-8467b74958-5qfwx   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          38s
trusted-enc-assettag1-deployment-8467b74958-zmlzl   0/1     ImagePullBackOff

Comment: You should configure the same thing on the Kubernetes worker node hosts. --> This is working, after configuration master and worker node performed docker restart now it is working. I couldn't understand then.

Comment: Hi, Can you describe clearly what is the current state of the your issues? I assume docker pull works but Kubernetes not? Can you provide minimal reproducible example with your config?

Comment: @thomas current state of issue - `solved`. I configured proxy.conf and NO_PROXY only in kuberenetes master. After performing the same configurations in kubernetes worker node and performed docker restart issue is solved. able to pull private registry image.

Answer (score 1):

If you use docker as container engine in your k8s, AFAIK it's the same with [Understand the configuration](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/#understand-the-configuration). Because the image pulling is conducted by the container engine and it depends the proprietary configuration of each one on the certificates. How about pulling the same image on the worker node in your k8s ? Is it possible to pull the one without errors ?

Comment: Same image pull from worker node gives the same error 

`[root@k8s-node ~]# docker pull 10.105.168.81:5000/simplehttpserverenc:enc_v1
Error response from daemon: Get https://10.105.168.81:5000/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout`

Comment: Hmm, you should had better check logs of 10.105.168.81 registry for more investigation. If the ca.crt is caused on the issue, then the error message would be "unknown authority ...". Please check if the request was reached the registry. Additionally if the proxy is placed between the registry and node, you should check if the proxy affect accessibility.

Comment: How to check logs, I tried docker registry it show command not found, and docker logs {options} <container ID> shows differently i'm not able to see logs related to this issue.

Comment: If you have not authority of the registry for checking the log messages, then you should check if the the certificate can be taken using "openssl s_client 10.105.168.81:5000". It's for accessibility verification through TLS handshake, if you are failed on this, it would not be k8s issue. You should contact your network administartor.

Answer (score 1):

As your `dockerconfigjson` is not working properly. Try this method :

`kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=10.105.168.81:5000 --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword>`

And in Kubernetes manifest :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: 10.105.168.81:5000/simplehttpserverenc:enc_v1
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

I had encounted this many times, when I forgot to configure these secrets. Also if you have any othernamespace, you will have to generate secrets for each of these namespaces separately passing `-n <your-ns>` to above `kubectl create secret`

Edit : As you can not pull the image from worker node.

1. Make sure you copied docker-registry `ca.crt` to `/etc/docker/certs.d/ca.crt`

and then try `docker pull` .

Comment: Unable to resolve by this method. 

private-reg                                         0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          2m

Comment: `docker pull 10.105.168.81:5000/simplehttpserverenc:enc_v1` try this from `k8s-node`, whether you can pull the image

Comment: No from Node unable to pull using docker, `[root@k8s-node ~]# docker pull 10.105.168.81:5000/simplehttpserverenc:enc_v1
Error response from daemon: Get https://10.105.168.81:5000/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
[root@k8s-node ~]#`

Comment: @imaheshwarans please check the updated answer.